# get full html source with selenium

Tags: selenium

I want to get the view count of a post in telegram. when I get the page source javaScript functions doesn't executed yet and so the data is not enabled. any help?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait    

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("https://t.me/varzesh3/106369")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME,'tgme_widget_message_views')))
```

I even tried it with Chrome driver but no change.

Comment: actually the output is TimeOutException now. cause driver can not find the class **'tgme_widget_message_views'** in the page source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a better Idea here. I can use bs4 with url https://t.me/varzesh3/106369?embed=1.

it's better because when you send the request by this url you have the iframe now.

and this is the code:

```
def generate_post_views(link):
   # https://t.me/varzesh3/106432
   html = requests.get(link + '?embed=1')
   plain_text = html.text
   soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
   try:
       views = soup.find('span', {'class':'tgme_widget_message_views'}).get_text()
   except AttributeError:
       views = 0
   return views
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not working because the element you want to check is inside an iframe. You need to first switch to IFrame.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait    

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://t.me/varzesh3/106369")
iframe = driver.find_element(By.ID,"telegram-post-varzesh3-106369")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME,'tgme_widget_message_views')))
```